# I want to select div tag with specific class. But my spider returns nothing when I run it?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler, bots

I want to **scrape** speakers' name from this link:
https://websummit.com/speakers

Name is basically in div tag with class="speaker__content__inner"

I made a spider in scrapy whos code is below

```
import scrapy

class Id01Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ID01'
    allowed_domains = ['websummit.com']
    start_urls = ['https://websummit.com/speakers']

    def parse(self, response):
        name=response.xpath('//div[@class = "speaker__content__inner"]/text()').extract()
        for Speaker_Details in zip(name):
            yield {'Speaker_Details': Speaker_Details.strip()}
        pass
```

When I run this spider it runs and returns nothing.
Log file:
https://pastebin.com/JEfL2GBu

P.S: This is my first question on stackoverflow, so please correct my mistakes if I made any while asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check source HTML (using `Ctrl+U`) you'll find that there is no speakers info inside HTML. This content is loaded dynamically using Javascript.

You need to call `https://api.cilabs.com/conferences/ws19/lists/speakers?per_page=25` and parse JSON.

Comment: Thank you for replying.
I understood what you are saying but I have one doubt.
I used xpath extension for chrome and it is showing this:
https://pasteboard.co/IikW6Cz.png
And I want this text only.

Comment: In your XPath extension your see a DOM *AFTER* applying all Javascript magic. Scrapy works with plain HTML but you can try to use Splash (https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)

Comment: There is Scrapy Splash.

Comment: Actually sir I am using Windows Home edition (and Docker is not installing on it) and my whole project is on it. So I think it is not possible for me to use splash on windows. Please guide me.